# Generation of schema scripts for all the objects across all databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Before DB deployment, we need to take backup of all the schema scripts (Tables with index & triggers, SPs, functions, table data types). We have more than 5 databases. Is there any automated way of taking scripts from all these objects across all the databases with different script file for every database?

Answer (score 2):

Related to https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56625? You don't specify how often and how many databases to script, but you did say 'automated'. The Powershell tooling for SQL Server is probably your best bet.